# Not working standby mode in the stm32l100

Tags: c, stm32, wakeup, standby, stm32ldiscovery

I'm tuning `stm32l100` for a *STANDBY* mode. The *MCU* should woke up 2 times per second. For this I use *RTC wakeup timer*. But after how *MCU* has entered to the *STANDBY* mode it immediately wakes up.

If instead the *STANDBY* mode I use a simple sleep-mode (**__WFI**) all works fine.

My code is here

1. After the *MCU* is starting

   a. saves flags *CSR_SBF* and *CSR_WUF*, after that clears them.

   ```
   if (PWR->CSR & PWR_CSR_SBF_BIT) {
      // ...
   }

   if (PWR->CSR & PWR_CSR_WUF_BIT) {
       // ...
   }

   PWR->CR |= PWR_CR_CSBF_BIT|PWR_CR_CWUF_BIT;

   //while (PWR->CSR & PWR_CSR_SBF_BIT);
   while (PWR->CSR & PWR_CSR_WUF_BIT);
   ```

   I noted that *CSR_SBF* never clears. If I uncomment string with `while` then *MCU* stall on it place. I don't understand why.

   b. saves reset source flags, after that clears them.

   ```
   volatile uint32_t csr;
   csr = RCC->CSR;

   // .... saving

   // clear flags
   RCC->CSR |= RCC_CSR_RMVF_BIT;
   ```

   After how *MCU* woke up from the *STANDBY* all reset source flags are cleared. It seems how reset sources are absent but code execute from 0x0.
2. Tuning *RTC wakeup-timer*

   ```
   void rtc_set_wakeup_mode(const uint32_t wakeup_counter)
   {
       RTC_WRITE_PROTECT_DISABLE();
       RTC->CR &= ~RTC_CR_WUTE_BIT;
       while (!(RTC->ISR & RTC_ISR_WUTWF_BIT));

       RTC->WUTR = wakeup_counter;
       RTC->CR &= 0xfffffff7;
       RTC->CR |= RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV2;

       __HAL_RTC_WAKEUPTIMER_EXTI_ENABLE_IT();
       __HAL_RTC_WAKEUPTIMER_EXTI_ENABLE_RISING_EDGE();

       RTC->CR |= RTC_CR_WUTIE_BIT|RTC_CR_WUTE_BIT;
       RTC_WRITE_PROTECT_ENABLE();
   }
   ```
3. Enter in the *STANDBY* mode

   ```
   void pwdm_enter_standby_mode(void)
   {
       PWR->CR |= PWR_CR_PDDS_BIT;
       SCB->SCR |= SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_BIT;

       __WFI();
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you look at the option bytes and check that entering standby doesn't reset the MCU?

Comment: I don't understand what is option bytes? After how the MCU returns from standby mode a value of `RCC->CSR` is 0x00420003

Comment: There is no source of reset in  RCC->CSR. The option bytes are special section of the FLASH and allow to specify some features for STM32. You can program them from STLink Utility.

Comment: @phodina A value of the option byte 'USER' by address `0x1FF80004` is `0xFF870078`

Comment: @phodina The MCU is remaining in STANDBY if I don't tune the wakeup-timer. It related with wakeup timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I got it.

It was my own fail with startup initialization. The key was in this:

> I noted that CSR_SBF never clears. If I uncomment string with while
>   then MCU stall on it place. I don't understand why.

I placed the code working with **wakeup/standby** flags at the begining of `main`. But this code didn't do this operation `__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();` because that operation will executed in a oscill initialization routine. So, the `PWR->CSR` was in undefined state and the `PWR_CSR_WUF` flag is never clearing.